# Get global IPv6 address from PPPoE link

Tags: ipv6, ppp, pppd

I'm paying extra to get an IPv4 address in my FTTH installation, which requires me to login via pppoe. rp-pppoe works fine and brings up the ppp0 interface with an IPv4 address and a link-local PtP IPv6 address (I've specified `+ipv6` in my pppd options). However, I am not receiving a global address. I'm assuming my provider is using Prefix Delegation for this purpose. What software do I need to learn my assigned IPv6 address and then (as a second step) to pass this information on to clients on my network?

Comment: Don't assume anything, ask you ISP how they are supplying IPv6 address space.